# ¿Cómo almacenar diferentes salidas de matriz de la cuál depende una consulta SQL en Python?

Tags: sql, python-2.7

Tengo una consulta SQL que depende de una tabla. Sin embargo no hace la distinción dentre las diferentes entradas de la tabla y quiero diferenciarlos.

La tabla del ejemplo siguiente esta una tabla de `subscriber_id` que interactúan con contenidos `eclipse_id`.

Por lo momento con esta tabla de grupos de `subscriber_id` para los grupos 0 y 1 :

```
res['ids']
grupos
0                                  [160, 161, 296]
1                                            [306]
```

Y esta tabula de `subscriber_id` que han interaciones con `eclipse_id` segun lo siguiente :

```
subscriber_id  eclipse_id
160            996
160            592
161            996
161            592
296            996
306            329
306            325
306            1214
```

Puedo hacer la consulta siguiente :

```
        for i, ids in enumerate(self.res['ids']):
            cur.execute("""--- hashtag qui decrivent le mieux les groupes
            SELECT COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id), 
            subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
            FROM subscriber_hashtag
            INNER JOIN eclipse_hashtag ON eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id = subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN swipe ON subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id = swipe.subscriber_id
            WHERE (swipe.state= 3 OR swipe.state = 6 or swipe.state=9) AND subscriber_hashtag.subscriber_id in %s
            GROUP BY subscriber_hashtag.hashtag_id
                ORDER BY COUNT(swipe.eclipse_id) DESC;""",
            (tuple(self.res.iloc[i]['ids']),))
        n = cur.fetchall()
        listado = [{"count": elem[0], "eclipse_id": elem[1]} for elem in n]
```

Y me da la siguiente salida :

```
[{'count': 3, 'eclipse_id': 996}, {'count': 2, 'eclipse_id': 592}, 
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 329}, {'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 325},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 1214}]
```

Pero no podemos saber qué resultado pertenece a cada grupo.

Queria, con los datos por mas alto :

```
[[{'count': 3, 'eclipse_id': 996}, {'count': 2, 'eclipse_id': 592}],[ 
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 329}, {'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 325},
{'count': 1, 'eclipse_id': 1214}]]
```

¿Pueden ayudarme hacerlo ?

Comment: Buenas, No llegué a comprender bien que es lo que se pretende lograr. ¿Podrías describir ejemplificando que resultado deseas obtener? Saludos!

Comment: @Blasito Gracias por su solicitud de aclaración. Intento de ayudar con una nueva redacción y informaciones adicional para explicar más claramente lo que quiero.